# Basic SQL mechanics, create table, then call that table from another script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two scripts that work in isolation, but I don't know how to stitch them together to do this all at once.

The first script:

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTES bq 
JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.PRODUCT p ON bq.ProductId = p.Id 
JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTEFEES F ON F.ApplicationQuoteId = bq.Id 
LEFT JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.COVERAGESECTIONTYPE CST ON F.CoverageSectionTypeID = CST.SECTIONID
```

This produces a table (is that the right word?). Suppose I could save that table as 'appQuote'. I then want to run this script on it:

```
SELECT
    ApplicationId, 
    STRING_AGG(YEARLYPAYAMOUNT) allPremium,
    STRING_AGG(SECTIONID) allSection,
    STRING_AGG(SHORTNAME) allSectionName,
FROM
    appQuote 
GROUP BY
    ApplicationId
```

For storage reasons I don't want to actually save the table from the first script, I just want to get the result from the first script and immediately apply the second script to it.

This is very basic, so any guidance would help.

Comment: As a hint, you can use your first query as a sub-query in the second.

Comment: What do you see if you run `select @@version`?

Comment: The use of 3 part names and the DBO mnemonic in the middle part indicates this is likely SQL Server, and not MySql. Also the STRING_AGG() function.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant term is known as a *derived table*.

In SQL you can use the result of a query as the input to another. The "nested query" produces the derived table which is then consumed by the outer query:

```
Select <columns>
from (
  select <columns> from table join table etc
)as TableAliasName
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the nomenclature right, what you have are not scripts or tables, but rather two **queries**. When a query runs it produces a **result set**.

To accomplish your goal, either of these queries will work:

```
SELECT
    ApplicationId, 
    STRING_AGG(YEARLYPAYAMOUNT) allPremium,
    STRING_AGG(SECTIONID) allSection,
    STRING_AGG(SHORTNAME) allSectionName,
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTES bq 
    JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.PRODUCT p ON bq.ProductId = p.Id 
    JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTEFEES F ON F.ApplicationQuoteId = bq.Id 
    LEFT JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.COVERAGESECTIONTYPE CST ON F.CoverageSectionTypeID = CST.SECTIONID
) appQuote 
GROUP BY
    ApplicationId
```

Here, the inner nested query is formally called a **derived table**, but people will often use the phrase "subquery".

The other option is a **Common Table Expression (CTE)**:

```
With appQuote As (
    SELECT *
    FROM PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTES bq 
    JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.PRODUCT p ON bq.ProductId = p.Id 
    JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTEFEES F ON F.ApplicationQuoteId = bq.Id 
    LEFT JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.COVERAGESECTIONTYPE CST ON F.CoverageSectionTypeID = CST.SECTIONID
)
SELECT
    ApplicationId, 
    STRING_AGG(YEARLYPAYAMOUNT) allPremium,
    STRING_AGG(SECTIONID) allSection,
    STRING_AGG(SHORTNAME) allSectionName,
FROM
    appQuote 
GROUP BY
    ApplicationId
```

---

Finally, you could also create a **View** from the first query:

```
CREATE View AppQuote As
    SELECT *
    FROM PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTES bq 
    JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.PRODUCT p ON bq.ProductId = p.Id 
    JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTEFEES F ON F.ApplicationQuoteId = bq.Id 
    LEFT JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.COVERAGESECTIONTYPE CST ON F.CoverageSectionTypeID = CST.SECTIONID
```

A view is not just a query; it will actually become part of the database, such that you can use it in many of the same ways you would use a table saved on disk, and then the second query in the original question will run unmodified.